# How to zoom out of screen in Lumia 535

Tags: settings, functionality, nokia-lumia-535

I think I'm accidentally pressing a button and it's zooming the screen of my Lumia 535. I can't zoom out of it, and only thing I do is restart the phone. How do I zoom out? It's like the tiles and everything goes massive sized so they don't even fit the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Settings->Ease of access i had to untick the magnifier. Now its okay.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have activated the *Screen magnifier* feature which is part of **Settings -> Ease of access**.

You can either disable it there or by **double-tapping the screen with two fingers**.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I have been suffering with the same problem for a while and also had to resort to rebooting the phone. I have tested it and the 2 finger tap toggles the magnifier off and on so hopefully no more problems if I accidently turn it on!